# Why are performance counters not used for cache attacks?

Tags: side-channel

Cache side-channel attacks rely on the capability to observe cache hits/misses for a given set. Usually this is done via timing information, e.g. in flush+reload or prime+probe. Why is the performance monitoring function of CPUs, e.g. the [Intel Processor Performance Monitoring](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/plattner/teaching/TrendsandConcepts/2010/Dementiev_Processor__Performance__Counter_Monitoring_by_Roman_Dementiev_14-07-2010.pdf) not used for cache attacks?

As far as I understand, the performance counters give information about the number of cache misses/hits. Using this assumption could you observe if a certain cache set was replaced by the victim? The attacker accesses a certain memory address, and observes if the number of cache misses increased by 1 instead of measuring the access time in the probe phase of prime+probe.

Is the only reason that the the performance monitoring units do not provide high enough resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows [you cannot read the performance counters from user mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45428588/569090), you [need a kernel module for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800266/569090).
When you have the option to install a kernel module there are much easier ways than a cache attack to get information from other processes.